# What do I get from the crane game?

Tags: kirbys-adventure

I am playing the 3D Classics version of Kirby's Adventure, and there is a room on the level select screen that you can go into and play a crane game.

I am not very good at it, and wasted a lot of time trying (and failing) to pick up any of the Kirby toys.

What happens if I do eventually manage to pick one up at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick up a small one, you get a single extra life. Each big one is worth 2 extra lives. It's essentially a source of direct lives, unlike the other Minigames where you stand to get points if you don't make it to a 1up.